# Having issue with signin page

Tags: php, session, authentication

After processing submitted data, my signing script redirects user back to index page. The problem is, in my index page I can't check if user signed in or not. I've inserted:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) 
{echo $_SESSION['id']; die();}
```

at the beginning of the index page for checking purposes. But it doesn't echo anything.
My signin script looks like this:

```
<?php
include '../includes/common.php';
$page='signin';
$err = array();

foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $get[$key] = filter($value);
}

if ($_POST['dologin']=='Daxil ol') {
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $data[$key] = filter($value);
    }

    $login = $data['login'];
    $pass = $data['pwd'];


    if (strpos($login,'@') === false) {
        $user_cond = "login='$login'";
    } else {
        $user_cond="email='$login'";
    }

    $result = $db->query("SELECT `id`,`pwd`,`fname`,`lname`,`approved`,`type`,`level` FROM users WHERE $user_cond AND `ban` = '0'") or die($db->error());

    $num = $result->num_rows;

    if ($num > 0 ) {
        list($id,$pwd,$fname,$lname,$approved, $type, $level) = $result->fetch_row();
        if (!$approved) {
            $err[] = 6;
        }
        if ($pwd === PwdHash($pass,substr($pwd,0,9))) {
            if (empty($err)) {

                session_start();
                session_regenerate_id(true);

                $_SESSION['id']= $id;
                $_SESSION['fname'] = $fname;
                $_SESSION['lname'] = $lname;
                $_SESSION['type'] = $type;
                $_SESSION['level'] = $level;
                $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

                $stamp = time();
                $ckey = GenKey();
                $db->query("update users set `ctime`='$stamp', `ckey` = '$ckey' where id='$id'") or die($db->error());

                //set a cookie

                if (isset($_POST['remember'])) {
                    setcookie("id", $_SESSION['id'], time()+60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
                    setcookie("key", sha1($ckey), time()+60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
                    setcookie("fname",$_SESSION['fname'], time()+60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
                }
                header("Location: ../../../index.php");
            }
        } else {
            $err[] = 7;
        }
    } else {
        $err[] = 8;
    }
    if (!empty($err)) {
    include "../includes/error.php";
    }

} 
?>
```

Checked php error log. No error. Also checked MySql DB tables. It sets ctime and ckey. The signin part works (I think).  The filter function is from `common.php` (for sanitizing post data)

Comment: Aren't you supposed to `session_start()` first before checking if there any `$_SESSION` variables are set?

Comment: Do you have session_start(); on your index page as well?

Comment: yes i have at the beginning of the page

Comment: Not the problem, but a problem is that you should not use relative paths for a `Location:` header. [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) states about the location header: `The field value consists of a single absolute URI`. You MUST use the absolute path of the new location. You can calculate this dynamically from `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` e.g. `header('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].rtrim(dirname(dirname(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']))),'/').'/index.php');`

Comment: but redirect works well. i wonder, how to start session if someone signs in or it doesn't matter if session will be active for guests too?

Comment: You can start the session when someone signs in as long as you don't send any content before you call `session_start()`. However, it's easier to have sessions for everyone - guests as well - and keep track of whether they are signed in or not in the session data. And yes, I'm sure your redirect does work in major browsers, but it technically shouldn't and there is no guarantee it will work everywhere (older browsers, mobile phones, etc etc) - it is good practice to pay attention to the standards...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start session (even before sending any headers to the page). You also need to start session on each page you need session data unless you have the [session auto start directive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start) set to true

```
<?php
session_start();
//$_SESSION data available here!
?>
<html>...
<?
   //other php code
   //$_SESSION data available here!
?>
...</html>
```

Comment: I edited, in both of them place session_start() in the beginning. In every page you need session data. Look at the links I posted!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing `session_start()` at the beginning of both files.

PHP wont pass session information if this function call is not present. It is a good practice to have this call be the first thing in the file.

Comment: I need to always start session in my index page?

Comment: Yes, all pages that will use session infomation need to have `session_start()`

Comment: i wonder, how to start session if someone signs in or it doesn't matter if session will be active for guests too?

Comment: `session_start()` is oblivious to whether a user has signed in or not. It is up to you as the programmer to determine what information gets saved in a session and is thus available between pages.